# Java script: Replace String Between Two variable

Tags: javascript

I need to replace string between two variable like this:

```
var str_before    = 'I Love My Cat So Much';
var start_mark    = 'My';
var end_mark      = 'So';
var str_replace   = 'Pussy Cat Very';

// Maybe

var after_replace = str_before.replace(start_mark, end_mark, str_replace);
// Replace String Between 'My' And 'So' With 'Pussy Cat Very'
// I Love Pussy Cat Very Much
```

Comment: Did you mean `/+ def + .*7/`?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes  like this one

Comment: So do you know how to fix it out?

Comment: The duplicate thread linked at the top of the page explains it.

Comment: thanks but that one replace only one variable,but i need to replace between two variable (like replace 1 between 7 with something else)  :(

Comment: What? Can you please [edit] your question to include the updated code that uses the `RegExp` constructor, and how it does not work?

Comment: Here something like this..

Comment: Wow. That question has nothing to do with regex any more. You might better [ask it as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: That said, `str.replace(new RegExp("("+start+").*("+end+")"), "$1"+replacement+"$2")` might do (assuming that all the variables do not contain special characters, or they would need to be escaped)

Comment: Oh @Bergi Thanks so much I want you to know how much I value your support...